# Adding/Enabling windows feature using chef

Tags: powershell, chef, cookbook

I am writing chef cookbook to add/enable some of the windows feature. For enabling I am using `powershell_script` resource and below is the powershell script.

```
Import-Module Servermanager
Add-WindowsFeature Print-LPD-Service
```

For some reason, during chef-client run windows feature is not enabled. But the recipe ran successfully.

When I manually executed the command in powershell shell it works fine.

I am not aware of any security settings to be enabled to achieve this requirement. So, how we can enable windows feature using chef. Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used `windows_feature` resource from `windows` cookbook instead of `powershell_script` resource to enable the features.

```
windows_feature 'Printing-LPDPrintService' do
  action :install
  not_if  { Registry.key_exists?('HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\LPDSVC') }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If it ran via the interactive shell, then you might not be allowed to run scripts on that machine.

You might need to put this at the beginning of your script:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Confirm:$false
```

The script needs to be run as an Administrator.

Comment: When using `powershell_script` resource, its executed as non-interactive. The command executed from chef-client log is `execute "powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -InputFormat None -File $TEMP_PATH`